# MS Word managing header and footer in a document with both landscape and portrait layouts

Tags: ms-word, word-processor

I have a document that has several sections, some with a portrait layout, and others with a landscape layout.

The document needs headers and footers on each page (the first page of the document is different from the others).

I am struggling to manage the headers and footers of the various sections work as formatting keeps changing unexpectedly even though the footers and headers of various sections are not linked.

My usual way to manage the formatting within headers and footers is to insert tables and all the content within. Unfortunately, when you change the page layout, the size of the tables changes, creating all sorts of problems.

Is there a way to address this issue in a consistent way? Ideally, I would like three types of header/footer templates: one for the first page, one for portrait pages and one for landscape pages.

For info, I am using MS Word for Mac (version 16.76.1).